# Setting a background image on Razor Pages Identity 'manage account' page

Tags: css, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to set a background-image on my Login and Manage account pages for ASP.NET Core Web application - I'm using Razor Pages identity, but it won't seem to change no matter where I put the CSS.

I tried putting it on the login page itself and also on the site CSS, but still nothing.

It has worked on my other pages but not on these.

my css is as follows:

```
body{
    background-image: url('hero-range-1.jpg');
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the  Logout page is under Identity area,so the url of background image will be `/Identity/hero-range-1.jpg`,so you need to put the image into `wwwroot/Identity`,here is a demo:

image root:

```
/wwwroot/Identity/hero-range-1.jpg
```

Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Login.cshtml:

```
...
<style>
    body{
        background-image: url('../hero-range-1.jpg');
        height: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: This works.  I wanted to add a logo to the Identity scaffolded page layout, so I was able to create a folder called Identity under the wwwroot folder, and then specify <img src="../SomeFile.png" height="48" /> in the server side layout.  Similiarly, I then moved the image to wwwroot/Indentity/images and called it as ../images/SomeFile.png .